# VB.NET referencing VB6 COM DLL gives an error in the production environment

Tags: vb.net, deployment, vb6

I have a VB6 DLL, which I am referencing in VB.NET, I am calling a function in it. It works fine in development environment, but not in the production environment.

> Error : 
>   Method not found: 'Boolean MyUtils._MyUtils.LoadMyObjectRecords(ADODB.Stream ByRef, System.Array ByRef)'.

Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have binary compatibility set?

Every time you compile a COM component created using VB6, a new GUID is created for the component. GUID's and CLSID's are the ones that identify a COM component from the registry. To avoid this binary compatibility is necessary. Read this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adam_nathan/archive/2003/10/19/56779.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have definitely have the same version of the DLL installed in your two environments?

Comment: Yes, I have same version at both environment

Comment: Yes , I have referring the DLL from the same location for both development and deployment setup

Answer (score 0):

Is MDAC (Microsoft Data Access Components) installed with the same version in the deployment environment as in the dev environment?

Latest version from MS is 2.8, IIRC: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I almost hate to ask this, but is the COM DLL registered on the deployed machine?